# Do we have to use Synchronize if we want to make some changes in the VCL main thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronize

Let's say that I want to simply change the caption of a Label when the program is in a child thread. I don't want use Synchronize. I really don't want to get the OS switch to another thread context to do this job. I know that I can't do this by just putting some lock(Semaphore or something) in my child thread. Can anyone tell me the reason why I can't use locks for that?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want a stable solution you must use `Synchronize` or `Queue`

Comment: @SirRufo Why can't I use just some locks? Isn't true that the vcl control is a typical shared resource? I mean why should VCL controls be treated in a different way?

Comment: You could also use [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to post a custom message to the VCL form's handle.

Comment: You are right @TOndrej. But as far as I know synchronize uses the same technique. I simply don't want to send any message or to put it better I don't want to get my job done in the main thread, rather I want to do it in the child thread. Did I lose the point here?

Comment: As an alternative you could use Windows APIs (working with Window handles directly) from the child thread and in some cases you can get away with it. But be careful, VCL assumes all over the place that it's running only in the main thread, and that VCL methods are used to manipulate the underlying windows. In some cases the underlying window can get out of sync with the properties of the VCL wrapper class.

Comment: @TOndrej, Seems that I didn't get the point here. Can I directly access a vcl object which is in the main thread from a child thread?

Comment: Not safely, sorry. VCL is not thread-safe.

Comment: A lock wouldn't help here as the VCL is simply not using it.

Comment: @Uwe,Maybe I could not get across my point correctly.
But you got my point very well.
Why can't we use locks for vcl objects in the same way we do for non-vcl objects. Is this due to some internal issue with the Delphi complier?

Comment: It's nothing at all to do with any compiler. No amount of locking in your code can help because the VCL does not see your lock. Window thread affinity is the other big issue. In any case, this limitation of VCL to the main thread is never an unsurmountable problem.

Comment: @TOndrej this sounds like a big issue to me, since almost all processor nowadays are multi-core... am I wrong?

Comment: @GabrielF Yes you are! GUI code is not CPU bound so multicore cannot improve perf. In fact perf isn't an issue for GUI updating. Modern computers can happily paint large screen fulls of stuff without breaking into a sweat. Generating the data to display may be CPU bound. But that's fine. Run that all in threads on multiple cores, and synchronise the display.

Comment: @UweRaabe - i did try. many years ago, to introduce a VCL lock by overriding Perform().  That didn't work either.  Since those early days, I have used PostMessage() exclusively for comms to the VCL main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do we have to use `Synchronize` if we want to make some changes in the VCL main thread?

Yes.

Well, code that accesses VCL objects has to execute on the main thread and `Synchronize` is the most commonly used way to achieve that. There is no way around that constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think my point here hasn't been understood very well.I do know that VCL classes like so many other classes are not thread safe. But we can still use non VCL classes in child threads and make them thread-safe by applying some synchronization rules(putting some locks etc). But my question is why we can't do the same thing for vcl classes. is this due to some internal problems or issues with Delphi?

Comment: Simply put the VCL is designed to be used exclusively within the main thread. For a start the Win32 design of windows having affinity to threads is reflected by the VCL. On top of that the VCL performs no serialization of its shared data structures because it is designed to be used entirely from the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is 100% correct. But I thought I'd shed a little more light...

Imagine this scenario: You have a VCL component with a number of properties which you want to update from a thread. You create a lock (such as a critical section) and any call in both your main VCL thread and additional thread you respect this lock whenever trying to access that object and its properties. However, since the VCL doesn't acknowledge the presence of other threads trying to use it, there may be something in the main thread which tries to access the same property that your thread is trying to access... *at the same time*. I'm not talking about your own code which might access this property, but something behind the VCL its self. There's no way that the VCL its self knows about your lock to acknowledge it.

Therefore, even the best locking mechanisms are not safe when working with anything in the main thread. Synchronize is an essential part of how multi-threading works, although there are a few alternatives such as feeding windows messages.

**Scenario**

Let's say you create a custom button component inherited from `TButton`. You create a thread behind this button and want to update the caption of the button from within this thread. You create a critical section lock to protect your control.

Let's also say that you have an action manager and this button is assigned to an action. The action manager is responsible for updating the caption of the button. While your thread and all your code respects the lock when accessing your button control, the action manager has no concept of this and tries to go ahead and update the caption anyway.

Comment: AFAIK, even things like FastMM, which are based off the main thread, might also interfere. Synchronize is really the only pure solution without resorting to dependencies like windows messages or memory mapped files.

Comment: Thanks for ur detailed answer. but I guess we could do something about
your scenario. we can override property setter and getter of that vcl class putting some lock codes into it. but i think it could seriously reduce the performance. am i right?

Comment: Is it really worth all that just to avoid using Synchronize?

Comment: No Jerry, that is really what I meant. it is not worth it. thanks again

Comment: Fastmm is threadsafe. Of course. You've omitted coverage of the window thread affinity issue.